# How to group data into not pre-determined intervals using R and dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I have this sort of data (simplified obviously):

```
Var1 Var2 Var3
20   0.4  a
50   0.5  a
80   0.6  b
150  0.3  a
250  0.4  b
```

I want to group them according to Var1 if they fall into an interval of 50, then get the mean of Var1 and Var2, and keep Var3 as is if it's homogeneous, or rename it if the group has mixed labels. In this case I would get:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3
50   0.5  mixed
150  0.3  a
250  0.4  b
```

I'm guessing I should use the `group_by` function from `dplyr` package but I don't know how exactly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please explain how exactly were your results created?

Comment: Can you explain in more details how do you define an interval? E.g. what will the intervals be for following vector c(20,50,80,110).

Comment: I have a table of results from various ChIP-seq experiments. Each line is a peak, Var1 is the coordinate of the peak summit, Var2 is the fold enrichment, and Var3 is a label describing the type of experiment. I want to group peaks together when they're likely to be the same peak coming out of different experiments. So a possible approximation is to consider that 2 peaks less than 50bp apart are the same peak.

Comment: In this case c(20,50,80,110) would be grouped together because 2 variables following each other are less that 50bp apart. It's a gross approximation, but in practice the values generally group closer to one another, and distinct groups are much further appart.

Comment: What if you had vector c(20, 50, 80, 110, 150, 190, etc.)? Is the trigger of a new group the existence of a gap of >=50?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the dataframe with `dput`

```
d <- structure(list(Var1 = c(20L, 50L, 80L, 150L, 250L), Var2 = c(0.4, 
0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.4), Var3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

I'd

1. create a few temporary columns to determine when a new group starts
2. group and calculate mean, but also track distinct values of Var3
3. change to mix if more than one Var3 value in a group

in the tidyverse this might look like

```
d %>% 
 # make sure we sort Var1
 arrange(Var1) %>% 
 # increment var1 by 50 and test that against the next row
 # if the next value exceeds current by 50, we mark it as a new group
 mutate(nextint=Var1+50, 
       newgroup=Var1>lag(nextint,default=-Inf), 
       grp=cumsum(newgroup)) %>%
 # for each group, get the mean and a comma separated list of distinct Var3 values
 group_by(grp) %>% 
 summarise(
           grplbl=floor(max(Var1)/50)*50,
           mu=mean(Var2), 
           mix=paste(collapse=",",unique(Var3))) %>%
 # if mix (distinct Var3) has a comma in it, change from e.g. 'a,b' to 'mix'
 mutate(mix=ifelse(grepl(',', mix), 'mixed', mix))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
    grp grplbl    mu mix  
  <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     50   0.5 mixed
2     2    150   0.3 a    
3     3    250   0.4 b
```

Comment: `grplbl=floor(max(Var1)/50)*50` works for the example but might fail if intervals span more than 50, `paste(collapse="-",range(Var1))` would be more informative

Comment: Neat! Mutate was the key piece I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(grp = cumsum(Var1 - lag(Var1, default = first(Var1)) > 50)) %>%
 summarise(Var1 = mean(Var1),
           Var2 = mean(Var2),
           Var3 = ifelse(n_distinct(Var3) > 1, "mixed", Var3)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp)

   Var1  Var2 Var3 
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1    50   0.5 mixed
2   150   0.3 a    
3   250   0.4 b
```

Comment: Works fine as well! Provided the data is already sorted. Thanks!